# Redirect output from terminal to libreoffice excel file

Tags: linux, libreoffice

I am running a code on a particular core and am monitoring the cache misses in that particular core every second when my code is running. I can redirect that output to a .txt file. I wanted to know if it is possible to redirect the output to a libreoffice excel file which will allow me to generate a graph easily.

Comment: Do you want Libreoffice, or do you want (Microsoft) Excel? But, more to the point, what have you tried, and what problems are you having?

Comment: this is an XY problem

Comment: @Tanktalus, I am monitoring in linux so I want a libreoffice file. I have tried to put in a .txt file and copy it to libreoffice to draw a graph. But it's quite time consuming.I wanted to directly redirect it to the libreoffice file.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg yes, I need X values and Y values for the graph. Is it possible to do that in spreadsheet format directly from the linux terminal?

Comment: lookup "XY problem".  The question you should ask is about how to generate graphs, not how to redirect terminal output to a spreadsheet.  redirecting output to a spreadsheet is part of your incorrect solution, not the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output the data into csv or tsv formatted file.

Any spreadsheet software will be able to open that as long as you have the format correct.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. It's being open by libreoffice. But everything is displayed under one column. There is no separation of columns. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: have you used the extension .csv and used commas as separators? You may also need to double quote strings. Take a look at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files

Comment: @Sabster If your locale uses `,` do separate decimals in numbers, you might have to use `;` instead of `,` to separate the columns.